# 3DES on iOS 8+ with Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, 3des

I have to encrypt a password with 3DES and send it as parameter to login service on backend.

I'm struggling searching an algorithm to achieve 3DES during last week but I can't be able to find it.

I need to crypt the password with a **key** and an **initializer vector** (aka **iv**).

Someone knows a free library or an algorithm appropriate?

Thanks.

Comment: No, I read the question last week and if you pay attention on the question text, you can see the user say "I have done encryption successfully". He's problem is decryption: in fact the code in the question is about decryption. My problem is encryption.

Comment: Swap `kCCDecrypt` for `kCCEncrypt`, add your init vector (which is commented out in their code), and you've got your solution.

Comment: Also remove `kCCOptionECBMode` option.

Comment: See [this SO answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30167657/451475) for a 3DES solution. The other option you need to consider is padding, 3DES has a 8-byte block size. Other possibile gotchas are EDE or DED mode and a 2 or 3 byte key. Note: 3DES should not be used for new work.