# Getting wrong Value after I decrypt the String using 3DES in Objective-c

Tags: ios, objective-c, encryption, 3des

3DES encryption is working fine and getting wrong values for decryption with same logic.

Please find the below logic to call Encryption / Decryption method

```
NSString *cipherEnString = [self doCipher:@"Test" enc:kCCEncrypt];
NSString *cipherDecString = [self doCipher:cipherEnString enc:kCCDecrypt];
```

And the code for Encryption / Decryption is added below.

```
- (NSString*) doCipher:(NSString*)plainText enc:(CCOperation)encryptOrDecrypt{
    const void *vplainText;
    size_t plainTextBufferSize;
    if (encryptOrDecrypt == kCCDecrypt)
    {
        NSString *encStr = [self encodeStringTo64:plainText];
        NSData *EncryptData = [encStr dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];        
        plainTextBufferSize = [EncryptData length];
        vplainText = [EncryptData bytes];
    }
    else
    {
        plainTextBufferSize = [plainText length];
        vplainText = (const void *) [plainText UTF8String];
    }

    CCCryptorStatus ccStatus;
    uint8_t *bufferPtr = NULL;
    size_t bufferPtrSize = 0;
    size_t movedBytes = 0;
    //  uint8_t ivkCCBlockSize3DES;

    bufferPtrSize = (plainTextBufferSize + kCCBlockSize3DES) & ~(kCCBlockSize3DES - 1);

    bufferPtr = malloc( bufferPtrSize * sizeof(uint8_t));
    memset((void *)bufferPtr, 0x0, bufferPtrSize);

    unsigned char secretKey[24]=  {0x01, 0x02, 0x03, 0x05, 0x07, 0x0B, 0x0D, 0x11,0x12, 0x11, 0x0D, 0x0B, 0x07, 0x02, 0x04,0x08,0x01, 0x02, 0x03, 0x05, 0x07, 0x0B, 0x0D, 0x11};
    unsigned char IV3[8]={0x01, 0x02, 0x03, 0x05, 0x07, 0x0B, 0x0D, 0x11};

    uint8_t iv[kCCBlockSize3DES];
    memset((void *) iv, 0x0, (size_t) sizeof(iv));

    ccStatus = CCCrypt(encryptOrDecrypt,
                       kCCAlgorithm3DES,
                       kCCOptionPKCS7Padding ,
                       secretKey, //"123456789012345678901234", //key
                       kCCKeySize3DES,
                       IV3 ,  //iv,
                       vplainText,  //plainText,
                       plainTextBufferSize,
                       (void *)bufferPtr,
                       bufferPtrSize,
                       &movedBytes);

    /*else*/ if (ccStatus == kCCParamError) return @"PARAM ERROR";
    else if (ccStatus == kCCBufferTooSmall) return @"BUFFER TOO SMALL";
    else if (ccStatus == kCCMemoryFailure) return @"MEMORY FAILURE";
    else if (ccStatus == kCCAlignmentError) return @"ALIGNMENT";
    else if (ccStatus == kCCDecodeError) return @"DECODE ERROR";
    else if (ccStatus == kCCUnimplemented) return @"UNIMPLEMENTED";

    NSString *result;
    if (encryptOrDecrypt == kCCDecrypt)
    {
        result = [ [NSString alloc] initWithData: [NSData dataWithBytes:(const void *)bufferPtr length:(NSUInteger)movedBytes] encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
        NSString *s = [[NSString alloc] initWithBytes:bufferPtr
                                               length:movedBytes
                                             encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        NSLog(@"%@",s);
    }
    else
    {
        NSData *myData = [NSData dataWithBytes:(const void *)bufferPtr length:(NSUInteger)movedBytes];
        NSString *base64String = [myData base64EncodedStringWithOptions:0];
        return base64String;
    }
    return result;
}

- (NSString*)encodeStringTo64:(NSString*)fromString
{
    NSData *plainData = [fromString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSString *base64String;
    if ([plainData respondsToSelector:@selector(base64EncodedStringWithOptions:)]) {
        base64String = [plainData base64EncodedStringWithOptions:kNilOptions];  // iOS 7+
    } 
    else {
        NSString *base64String = [plainData base64EncodedStringWithOptions:0];
        NSLog(@"%@", base64String);// pre iOS7
    }
    return base64String;
}
```

Comment: What do you get and what do you expect?

Comment: Please see http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve for help in asking your question. Please also remove all the extra blank lines in your code; it makes it very difficult to read.

Comment: It seems user3383223 may be the same as user Nandy, if so please use the same user id. See similar [question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/35552641/451475) by Nandy.

Comment: 3DES really should not be used in new work, use AES.

Comment: Consider accepting answers that are helpful. 

To accept an answer click on the hollow checkmark next to the answer that is best, doing so will increase your reputation and allow more capabilities, See [reputation faq](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#reputation)  See [this page](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) for more detail.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to hard to convert the base64 encrypted string to encrypted data:

Current:

```
NSString *encStr = [self encodeStringTo64:plainText];
NSData *encryptData = [encStr dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

Correct:

```
NSData *encryptData = [[NSData alloc] initWithBase64EncodedString:plainText options:0];
```

Additionally you don't need the method:

```
- (NSString *)encodeStringTo64:(NSString*)fromString
```

Adding a couple of hex dumps of the data to be encrypted/decrypted before and after would show this problem.

It is also better to create a basic encryption method that takes and returns `NSData` and add methods that perform any encoding/decoding that call the encryption method. Less co-mingling of responsibilities makes the code simpler and easier to understand and debug.

See this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30167657/451475) to see how to eliminate `malloc` and instead just use `NSMutableData` instead.